# Non-cooperative cancellation of an asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

In my Windows Form application I need to call a long-running operation of a 3rd party math library (Accord.NET). During computation I want to keep my GUI responsive and also give the user the possibility to cancel the long-running operation.

Is there a way to execute that function in a background thread and giving the user the possibility to cancel it? Note that the long-running function I'd like to call is in an external library and does not accept a `CancellationToken` (otherwise I could easily use `ThreadPool`'s `QueueUserWorkItem`, for example). So I am looking for a way to non-cooperatively cancel the operation.

Comment: Why don't you use managed threads?

Comment: The only safe way to do it is by running that code in a separate AppDomain.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Do you have an example of how to execute a function in a separate AppDomain? And I guess there is quite some overhead involved in creating and destroying a new AppDomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you have three choices.

One, spin the calculation into it's own thread.  This will keep the UI responsive.  Instead of a cancel button, just let the user know the action the are about to take can't be stopped once stared.

Two, spin the calculation into it's own thread just like above; however, *pretend* to cancel it by simply reducing the threads priority.  You can let the calculation keep going, but just stop reporting progress in your main thread.  When it's done just throw away the results.

Three, put the calculation into it's own appdomain/process.  If desired, kill that external process.

---

There are good and bad things about each one.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of orphaning the thread, starving it and letting it die, alone, of neglect, with no-one to mourn it, no eulogy, no epitaph (sob..)

Comment: @MartinJames: ;)  Some old Mötley Crüe lyrics come to mind in situations like this: Don't go away mad, just go away...

Answer (score 1):

huh? Just use a Thread and a worker method.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(MyWorkerMethod);
thread.Start();

thread.Abort();


void MyWorkerMethod() {
    // do anything you want in here
}
```

Comment: if he uses a protected code block (eg a catch-block). in any other case there shouldn't be a problem. or do i miss something?

Comment: It looks like I missed the most obvious solution... :) thanks @ChrisB for pointing this out.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: If I understand the documentation of `Thread.Abort` correctly, it should not be a problem to use it as long as my worker function does not hold any locks and does not call any static constructors and as long as I use .Net 2.0 or later. I'm pretty sure that the algorithm I want to call does not need any locks. However I'm not so sure about the static constructors...

Comment: If the thread you are aborting is running 3rd-party code as the OP mentions, why does it matter whether you Abort it? All the articles against Thread.Abort() I have read are criticizing its use as part of a design, not in relation to 3rd party code. Even [Peter Ritchie's article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/08/22/thead-abort-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx) comments "If it's not your code then (i.e. it's code out of your control) yes, you have no choice"

Comment: It's not very often that 3rd-party code is a complete black hole.  Uusally, it calls, opens, reads, does something that can be signaled to raise some sort of exception.  This appears to be a math library, so you could perhaps set all the data it was passed to zero and wait for an exception to emerge.